# Run all unit & instrumentation in all modules Gradle android

Tags: android, gradle

I have a project and have many modules inside it, and each module has unit tests and instrumentation tests. Every time I run a test I have to set the the target module in the configuration. Which is tiring to do.

Is there any gradle command to run all modules tests in one run?

btw, I can run in terminal this command. But can execute it one by one.

```
./gradlew module-a:connectedAndroidTest
./gradlew module-b:connectedAndroidTest
./gradlew module-c:connectedAndroidTest
```

Thanks

Comment: how do you execute currently? `gradle test`?

Comment: in android studio there's an option edit configurations beside the run button (the green triangle at the top). Add android test (clicking the + sign at the top left) then select the module to test. and hit run. to run the test of that module

Comment: try using the command `gradle test` to execute them on console on your project directory

Comment: ./gradlew module-a:connectedAndroidTest this works on mine

Answer (score 8):

The following command:

`gradlew test connectedAndroidTest`

Should run all you unit and instrummented tests.